# DataGridView CellValueChanged not triggered

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am facing a wierd problem right now with a datagridview.

I cannot leave blank in a datagridview cell if it previously had a value.

Once i've loaded data in my cell if i change the value the CellValueChanged event is well triggered.

However if i delete the cell's content and click elsewhere nothing happens, CellValueChanged  is not triggered.
The cell keep the focus until i enter a value.
I cannot leave blank in the cell if the cell previously had a value.

I must be missing something obvious but i can't tell what.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the cell is not loaded with data i can enter and leave it with a blank. The problem seems to occur once i've entered data in it.

Comment: I just found. For those who might face the same problem it came from the valuetype of the cell which was set somewhere deep in the code.